# How to prevent duplicating nested elements on update with D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, svg

I've created an SVG element for each data item. Now I want to append a path element to each svg, but when I update the data, instead of using the same element, it duplicates it. How do I prevent this?

My data looks something like this:

```
var dataset = [
     {"id": 1, "goalPct": 1, "curPct": 0.5},
     {"id": 2, "goalPct": 1, "curPct": 0.25},
     {"id": 3, "goalPct": 1, "curPct": 0.74}
];
var dataset2 = [
     {"id": 1, "goalPct": 1, "curPct": 0.74},
     {"id": 2, "goalPct": 1, "curPct": 0.5},
     {"id": 3, "goalPct": 1, "curPct": 0.25}
];
```

Now, from this data I've created an svg element. This works just like it should, on the update call (when I push the new data in), it doesn't duplicate. code:

```
var svg = container.selectAll("svg").data(data);
svg.enter()
   .append("svg");

svg.exit().remove();
svg.transition().duration(750)
```

From here, I want to append a path element to those svg elements, but when I push the new data in, it just appends a new path element instead of updating it with the new data. I can't use the .data(data) function to the path elements because if I do, it creates a path for each data element on *each* svg. (e.g. if I have 2 data elements and 3 svg's, it will create 2 path elements on each of the 3 svg's). code:

```
var arc = svg.append("path")
        .attr({
            "d": function (d, i) {
                bronzeArc.endAngle((2 * Math.PI) * d.CurPct);
                return bronzeArc();
            }
        });
```

I've tried moving the svg.exit().remove(); around and that doesn't help me out any. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow what you're trying to achieve. could you get this up on a codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: @rcheuk http://jsbin.com/wiqalixudu/edit?js,output

It will make more sense if you are able to F12 it because you'll be able to see what I'm talking about when I say it's piling up the elements. In essence, the 2 circles should swap angles, but instead only 1 of the circles are changing because the elements are just piling ontop of each other. The reason 1 is changing is because the new data is greater than the last. Does that make a little more since?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your `append('path')` call onto the enter selection. Right now you are always adding a new path even if one already exists. Try something like this:

```
var svg = container.selectAll("svg")
    .data(data);
svg.enter()
    .append("svg")
    .append("path");

svg.exit()
    .remove();

var arc = svg.select("path")
    .attr({
        "d": function(d, i) {
            bronzeArc.endAngle((2 * Math.PI) * d.CurPct);
            return bronzeArc();
        }
    });
```

Now you will only append paths to new svgs, and you will update the `d` attr on all paths.

Comment: This works to some extent. What am I suppose to do when I want multiple paths appended to the svg? If I continue to just append, they get nested to the previous element. e.g. if I were to add another append method after the first path, it would nest it in that first path element.

Comment: Disregard. I just figured it out. Thank you sir!